# Upload multiple files from Flutter app to Net 5 server returns 400 request

Tags: flutter, .net-core, .net-5

I keep getting 400 bad request saying that my file is missing yet when i look at the request i can see all the required files.

Flutter code:

```
 Future<bool> uploadArtefacts(String objectId, String objectType, List<Uint8List> artefacts) async {
    var request = http.MultipartRequest(
        'POST', Uri.parse(uriString));

    for (var artefact in artefacts) {
      request.files.add(http.MultipartFile.fromBytes('Artefacts', artefact));
    }

    request.fields['objectType'] = objectType;
    request.fields['objectId'] = objectId;
    try {
      var streamedResponse = await request.send();
      var response = await http.Response.fromStream(streamedResponse);
      if (response.statusCode == 204) {
        return true;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      log(e.toString());
    }

    return false;
  }
```

My controller

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadArtefact([FromForm] ArtefactDTO artefactDTO)
{
   if (!ModelState.IsValid)
   return BadRequest(ModelState);
   /// omitted for brevity
    
   return NoContent();
}
```

ArtefactDTO

```
public record ArtefactDTO(
      [Required]
      string ObjectType,
      Guid ObjectId,
      [Required]
      List<IFormFile> artefacts,
      string Description);
```

Request output

[image]

Response

```
"errors":{"artefacts":["The artefacts field is required."]}
```

Comment: Check if the server works okay using postman or something.

Comment: Wouldn't you need to give each `MultipartFile` it's own `field` value (the first parameter). You are adding several, but calling them all `'Artefacts'`. How can the server differentiate which is which?

Comment: @RichardHeap that is as intended. If you want to send array of files under a name "artefacts" you have to give the multipart name as "artefacts" and it adds it to existing array (or creates array first), not to be confused with filename. So the server receives array of artefacts, containing a list of multipart files, and then you can iterate through each file.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason Multipart class wasn't creating full formed multipart files using the fromBytes method.

Resolved it by changing it to fromPath, it worked fine.